# Проблема при отображении html в android

Tags: html, парсер, android

Пытаюсь запихнуть html код страницы в переменную и отобразить ее, но при исполнении такого кода:

```
 private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String http = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(16384);

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com.ua/");

        try {
            HttpResponse responce = client.execute(get);
            InputStream content = responce.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            while ((http = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(http);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        editTxt.setText(s);

    }
}
```

вылетает ошибка, и приложение крашится.

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Разрешение на доступ к интернету в манифесте дано.
Подскажите в чем дело? Может есть способ попроще для этого?

logcat:

```
08-08 16:54:25.030  23105-23236/com.example.ron.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:430)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
        at com.example.ron.myapplication.MainActivity$SearchTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:93)
        at com.example.ron.myapplication.MainActivity$SearchTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:80)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname) 
        at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:59)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405) 
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Текст ошибки -- существенная часть вопроса.

Comment: "Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)"  в логе говорит, что разрешение все же не дано ...

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что uses-permission на INTERNET присутствует в манифесте. В чем еще может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы.
В манифесте стоит писать

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

вместо

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

В андроид студии есть такой "баг". Когда начинаешь писать permission с большой буквы, то появляется правильный автокомплит, но записывает строку всю большими буквами, но при этом верная строка, это когда последняя часть большими буквами записана, а все сотальные маленьки. Приложение просто игнорирует неправильную строку. Тоже сталкивался с этой проблемой. Решенее простое. Надо себя научить писать маленькими, тогда автокомплит правильную строку выдаст.